# pass variable of javascript to php to the current page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have read in many place that i can t pass a variable of js to the php code but i don t understand why, ok i know that it isn t so tidy make that but i didn t know why i could do that, here i have a few trys but i cant achieve anything

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
<script> 
function myFunction() {


    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var str="holi58";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


</script>





<?php

echo $_POST['q'];
echo $_REQUEST['q'];
echo $_GET['q'];
echo $_REQUEST["q"];

?>
```

[image]

here you can see that the netword detect that arrive the request but i not understand why the page don t show the value

Comment: You need to write java script to update the page. It's not going to auto load the page. Thus the purpose of Ajax call.

Comment: something like this "location.reload();"

Comment: Back when I was trying to get this to work, I remember reading that only form submissions will load the response. Wrap your button in a <form>.

Comment: no that don t work :(